# Numpy column_stack (46020, 369) (46020,) (46020,) (46020,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've 4 arrays with the following shapes:

```
     X         pred1    pred2   pred3
(46020, 369) (46020,) (46020,) (46020,)
```

I'm trying to concat the column from the last 3 into the X.
if I do for example:

```
array_pack = np.column_stack((X, pred1, pred2, pred3))
```

it gives me a error:

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the
>   concatenation axis must match exactly

What I'm doing wrong? 
and should the arrays with the shape of (46020,) be like (46020, 1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [numpy's `atleast_2d()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html) on pred1, pred2, and pred3 to ensure the arrays are at least two dimensions, i.e.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(46020,369)
pred1 = np.random.rand(46020)
pred2 = np.random.rand(46020)

print X.shape,pred1.shape,pred2.shape
```

(46020, 369) (46020,) (46020,)

Then, you can use `np.vstack` to concatenate the arrays.

```
# concatenate
X_new = np.vstack(np.atleast_2d(X.T,pred1,pred2)).T
print X_new.shape
```

(46020, 371)

Comment: tks for the help, this raise other error: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (46020,369) into shape (46020)

Comment: Sorry, I was sending the arguments to atleast_2d incorrectly. See the edited version above.

Comment: Tks for the all the tryies but still the same ... ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: atlead_2d adds the 2nd axis at axis=0, so we need to transpose X, concatenate, then transpose again.

Comment: Tks man i did not realize that you change to vstack, now it works! tks again